# SwiftyJSON & Swift 3: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int32?' to return type > 'Int?'

Tags: cocoapods, swift3, swifty-json

We are upgrading to SwiftyJSON Swift 3 with CocoaPods config `pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.1.0'`.

We are getting this error:

> /Users/xxx/Documents/iOS/xxx/Pods/SwiftyJSON/Source/SwiftyJSON.swift:866:33:
>   Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int32?' to return type
>   'Int?'

Error is on the return statement in SwiftyJSON.swift:

```
public var int: Int? {
    get {
        return self.number?.int32Value
    }
    set {
        if let newValue = newValue {
            self.object = NSNumber(value: newValue)
        } else {
            self.object = NSNull()
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know what the issue is?  Is this an issue with our CocoaPods config or with SwiftyJSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realized the [supported version](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/647) of SwiftyJSON is 3.0.0 and not 3.1.0.  Used 3.0.0 and the issue went away.

`pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'`

Comment: Did you run the pod update command and let it complete?  And do a full clean and build?

Answer (score 8):

I Just replace one line of code with below code. Simple

```
public var int: Int? {
        get {
            return self.number?.intValue
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                self.object = NSNumber(value: newValue)
            } else {
                self.object = NSNull()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's valid but our objective is not to modify the client library source.

Comment: Yes. i agree with you. we should not modify it. But if we want temp solution to remove erro, we can use above code. In future, we will remove it definatly.

Answer (score 0):

simply try this,

> Bad :  return self.number?.int32Value
>
> Good : return self.number?.intValue
>
> Reason : Seems to be more generic in how it can return integers.

Answer (score 0):

I manually added `as? Int` to get this working again:

```
public var int: Int? {
    get {
        return self.number?.int32Value as? Int
    }
    set {
        if let newValue = newValue {
            self.object = NSNumber(value: newValue)
        } else {
            self.object = NSNull()
        }
    }
}
```